# Count-Up and Count-Down Timer with Date() in Swift 4 should stop after a certain time period

Tags: ios, swift, date, timer

I am quite new to Swift and already learned a lot using the questions here.

In one of my first projects I try to write a soccer playtime timer app. The first timer is counting up after the whistle button is pressed showing the minutes played and the second timer is counting down to zero showing the minutes left to play. This works so far.

Now both timers should stop automatically when the halftime is over, so that I can start a third overtime timer. So far the invalidate statement of the timer is not working - both timers keep running. There seems to be something wrong with my if-statements, but at the moment I have no clue what. So any help would be very appreciated.

```
var countUpClock: Timer?
var countDownClock: Timer?

private var formatter: DateComponentsFormatter = {
    let formatter = DateComponentsFormatter()
    formatter.unitsStyle = .positional
    formatter.allowedUnits = [.minute, .second]
    formatter.zeroFormattingBehavior = .pad
    return formatter
}()

func runPlaytimeClocks() {

    let startTime = Date()
    let countTime = Date() + 2700 //45min of playtime

    if startTime <= countTime {
        countUpClock = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.0, repeats: true) { [weak self] _ in
        self?.timePlayed.text = self?.formatter.string(from: startTime, to: Date())
        }
    }
    else {
        countUpClock?.invalidate()
        }


    if startTime <= countTime {
        countDownClock = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: -1.0, repeats: true) { [weak self] _ in
            self?.timetoPlay.text = self?.formatter.string(from: Date(), to: countTime)
            }
        }
    else {
        countDownClock?.invalidate()
}
```

Comment: You can’t have a negative time interval. That would mean that the timer fires 1 second in the past?!

Comment: You can do while your startTime is equal to countTime, then you can start a third overtime timer.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you very much for the replies.

I found exactly what I was looking for here: http://ioscake.com/swift-nstimer-in-background.html

I adapted the solution to my for clocks (CountUpClock, CountDownClock, OvertimeClock, HalftimeClock).

Do you have any suggestions what would be the best solution to start the second halftime of the soccer game?

So far the CountUpClock starts again at 0:00 when I press the whistle button after the halftime break. But it should keep running from minute 45:00 to 90:00 - while the CountDownClock should counting down from 45:00 to 0:00 again.

What would be the best solution for such a behaviour?

```
import UIKit
import UserNotifications

private let stopTimeKey = "stopTimeKey"

class ViewController: UIViewController {

//Outlets
@IBOutlet weak var timePlayed: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var timeToPlay: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var overtime: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var halftime: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var halftimeButton: UIButton!

private var stopTime: Date?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    registerForLocalNotifications()

    stopTime = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: stopTimeKey) as? Date
    if let time = stopTime {
        if time > Date() {
            startTimers(time, includeNotification: false)
        } else {
            notifyTimerCompleted()
        }
    }
}

private func registerForLocalNotifications() {
    if #available(iOS 10, *) {
           UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound]) { granted, error in
            guard granted && error == nil else {
                // display error
                print("\(String(describing: error))")
                return
            }
        }
    } else {
        let types: UIUserNotificationType = [.badge, .sound, .alert]
        let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(types: types, categories: nil)
        UIApplication.shared.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
    }
}
//Actions
@IBAction func whistleButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    overtimeClock?.invalidate()
    overtimeClock = nil
    halftimeClock?.invalidate()
    halftimeClock = nil
    overtime.text = "00:00"
    halftime.text = "00:00"
    halftimeButton.isHidden = true
        //add 10 seconds per halftime to try out
        let time = Date() + 10
        if time > Date() {
            startTimers(time)
        } else {
            timeToPlay.text = "error"
        }
    }

@IBAction func halftimeButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    halftimeButtoPressed()
}

// Code for different Timers

private var countDownClock: Timer?
private var countUpClock: Timer?
var overtimeClock: Timer?
var halftimeClock: Timer?

private func startTimers(_ stopTime: Date, includeNotification: Bool = true) {
    // save `stopTime` in case app is terminated

    UserDefaults.standard.set(stopTime, forKey: stopTimeKey)
    self.stopTime = stopTime

    // start Timer

    countDownClock = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.1, target: self, selector: #selector(handleCountDownTimer(_:)), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

    countUpClock = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.1, target: self, selector: #selector(handleCountUpTimer(_:)), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

    guard includeNotification else { return }

    // start local notification (so we're notified if timer expires while app is not running)

    if #available(iOS 10, *) {
        let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
        content.title = "Overtime is starting soon"
        content.body = "In 5 seconds the overtime will start"
        content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()
        //5 seconds warning before overtime starts
        let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: stopTime.timeIntervalSinceNow - 5, repeats: false)
        let notification = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "timer", content: content, trigger: trigger)
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(notification)
    } else {
        let notification = UILocalNotification()
        //5 seconds warning before overtime starts
        notification.fireDate = stopTime - 5 
        notification.alertBody = "Overtime is starting soon"
        UIApplication.shared.scheduleLocalNotification(notification)
    }
}

private func stopTimer() {
    countDownClock?.invalidate()
    countDownClock = nil
    countUpClock?.invalidate()
    countUpClock = nil
}

private func halftimeButtoPressed() {
    overtimeClock?.invalidate()
    overtimeClock = nil
    startHalftimeClock()
    halftimeButton.isHidden = true
}

private let dateComponentsFormatter: DateComponentsFormatter = {
    let _formatter = DateComponentsFormatter()
    _formatter.allowedUnits = [.minute, .second]
    _formatter.unitsStyle = .positional
    _formatter.zeroFormattingBehavior = .pad
    return _formatter
}()

@objc func handleCountDownTimer(_ timer: Timer) {
    let now = Date()

    if stopTime! > now {
        timeToPlay.text = dateComponentsFormatter.string(from: now, to: stopTime!)
    } else {
        stopTimer()
        notifyTimerCompleted()
        startOvertimeClock()
        halftimeButton.isHidden = false
    }
}

@objc func handleCountUpTimer(_ timer: Timer) {
    //add 10 seconds per halftime to try out
    let now = Date() + 10

    if now > stopTime! {
        timePlayed.text = dateComponentsFormatter.string(from: stopTime!, to: now)
    } else {
        stopTimer()
        notifyTimerCompleted()
    }
}

//Overtime Clock
@objc func startOvertimeClock() {

    let startOvertime = Date()

    overtimeClock = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.1, repeats: true) { [weak self] _ in
        self?.overtime.text = self?.dateComponentsFormatter.string(from: startOvertime, to: Date())
    }
}

//Halftime Clock
@objc func startHalftimeClock() {

    let startHalftime = Date()

    halftimeClock = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.1, repeats: true) { [weak self] _ in
        self?.halftime.text = self?.dateComponentsFormatter.string(from: startHalftime, to: Date())
    }
}

private func notifyTimerCompleted() {
    timeToPlay.text = "End"
    timePlayed.text = "End"
}

}
```